# How to loop through the first column inside a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to loop through the first column called `title` in my existing CSV file. 
[picture of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVCQ8.png)

I achieve the for loop but I have two commas at the end of each title that I need to remove. I don't know where the commas are coming from.

My Output is:

```
(venv) C:\amazon_bot>python amazon_bot.py

halo 5,,

dark souls 3,,

code vein,,
```

My code is here:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    items = f.readlines()[1:]
    for items in f:
        print(items)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this neatly with a [CSV DictReader](https://kite.com/python/docs/csv.DictReader). We add the columns to lists based on the header. So, if your header is 'title' for the column that contains halo 5, etc., as you show in your picture, then you will get a dictionary key 'title' that maps to the list `['halo 5',...]`. We then print these titles using `print(contents['title'])`.

```
with open('test.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        # read the file as a dictionary for each row ({header : value})
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        contents = {}
        for row in reader:
            for header, column_content in row.items():
                if column_content not in (None, ''):
                    try:
                        contents[header].append(column_content)
                    except KeyError:
                        contents[header] = [column_content]
         for title in (contents['title']):
             print(title)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried the code on my program but it didn't loop through each title name. It did store them in a dictionary but I need the titles to print one after another

Comment: What is stored in the dictionary when you print it?

Comment: i need it to print each value one after another

Comment: I just added that to my solution. Please be more clear about these specifics in the future!